# How to print the count of passes and failures as sequence of 1s and -1s

Tags: perl, loops

I wrote this script in perl, where I extract the pass count and failure count and print it as 1 and -1. 
Below is what I have tried and it works fairly well but I want to know if there is a way that I can improvise the code?

```
my $pc = 10;
my $fc = 5;
my $v = "";
my $c = 0;

while ($c < $pc){
    if ($c > 0) {
        $v .= ",";
    }
    $c++;
    $v .= "1";
}
$v .= ",";
$c=0;
while ($c < $fc){
    if ($c > 0) {
        $v .= ",";
    }
    $c++;
    $v .= "-1";
}
print $v;
print "\n";

output:1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
```

Appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Write some more code after $c=0; to print a ","?

Comment: Jeroen Heier: Thanks, I did and it took care of the ",". However is there a way I can further improvise this code? especially with the while loop?

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use unintelligible single-character identifiers for your variables? Sensible identifiers together with the English keywords of the language should produce a program that is readable. If you stop someone on the street they will have no idea what you might mean by `$pc` or `$fc`, but everyone would know `$pass_count` and `$fail_count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl offers a wide-range of higher-level tools, and often we don't need  explicit loops.

A direct answer to the question

```
my $v = join ',', (1) x $pc, (-1) x $fc;
```

We build the list of `1`s using the [repetition operator (`x`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) on the list `(1)`. Since all that follows the pattern in [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) is its input list, we can also supply the list of `-1`s, using the [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) between them. Elements of this combined (*flattened*) list are then joined by `,`

If you need to resolve dynamically anything about those `1`s there'll be more work to do.

---

Here is another approach, which is suitable for more general conditions.

The  part with `+1`

```
my $v = join ',', map { 1 } 1..$pc;
```

and the part with `-1`

```
$v .= join ',', map { -1 } 1..$fc;
```

This can also be made into one line like the first example, if desired and suitable.

The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) runs the code in the block for each element of the input list, and returns the resulting list. Inside the block each element is available in the [$_ variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) and the code normally uses it. This is how we can generate a list from another, in a functional manner.

But in this example you only want the list of `1`s, so `1` is returned from the block each time, `$pc` times.  Then that output list becomes input to [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) and elements are joined by `,`. The second line does this `$fc` times for `-1`, then appending the joined string to `$v`.

Comment: Use a [subroutine](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_subroutines.htm) If you want to use this code on more places

Comment: @JeroenHeier  That is probably a good advice, for the OP when implementing this in their code. Presumably it _is_ in some subroutine.

Comment: @zdim: Thank you for this, it makes my code looks much more simpler.

Comment: @JeroenHeier: Yes, I have this script as subroutine.

Comment: @anyname  You are welcome.  The moral to take -- there is indeed a large range of tools and techniques in Perl and it is a very good idea to get familiar with them.  Also, please see the update.  And please check back later or in a day or two, I may update more.  If I should explain any of it more please let me know.

Comment: Downvoted? If anyone can see why that may be, please drop a line here.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an array for storing the output which is a more structured way to handle multiple values.Please Find Below the code I have modified.

```
my $pc = 10;
my $fc = 5;
my @v;
my $c = 0;
$c=$pc;
while ($c){
    push @v, "1";
    $c--;
}
$c=$fc;
while ($c){
    push @v, "-1";
    $c--;
}
local $, = ',';
print @v;
print "\n";
```

Note - Please note that the output is in an array and the separator (,) is just used for formatting the output and is not present in the array. Using `$, = ','` we can set any thing as an output separator.

Comment: No reason to use `local $, = ',';
print @v;
print "\n";` instead of `print(join(',', @v), "\n");`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix the bug where `$pc == 0` and `$fc > 0` returns `,-1,-1,...` instead of `-1,-1,...`.

```
my $v = "";
my $c = 0;
for (1..$pc) {
    $v .= "," if $c++ > 0;
    $v .= "1";
}
for (1..$fc) {
    $v .= "," if $c++ > 0;
    $v .= "-1";
}
```

Second, let's use an array to collect the values, and join the contents in order to avoid all that comma code.

```
my @v;
for (1..$pc) {
    push @v, "1";
}
for (1..$fc) {
    push @v, "-1";
}

my $v = join(',', @v);
```

That looks an awful lot like the definition of `map`<sup>[1]</sup>! So,

```
my @v;
push @v, map {  "1" } 1..$pc;
push @v, map { "-1" } 1..$fc;
my $v = join(',', @v);
```

Or just

```
my $v = join ',',
   map({  "1" } 1..$pc),
   map({ "-1" } 1..$fc);
```

Finally, since the body of the `map` is constant, we can use the repetition operator.

```
my $v = join ',',
   (  "1" ) x $pc,
   ( "-1" ) x $fc;
```

---

1. Which is to say

   ```
   my @v; for (LIST) { push @v, f($_) }
   ```

   can be written as

   ```
   my @v = map { f($_) } LIST;
   ```